# How to correctly mock the library "Twemoji" when running unit tests in angular + jest?

Tags: angular, jestjs, twemoji

My objective is to run unit tests in my Angular application with jest, without getting:

```js
error TS2304: Cannot find name 'twemoji'
```

[Twemoji](https://github.com/twitter/twemoji) is added to the projects `package.json` and the `angular.json` file, scripts section. It works perfectly when running and building the application, but fails with the above error when running unit tests.

**What I have tried**

I have tried adding the following to my `src/jestGlobalMocks.ts` file:

```js
declare var twemoji: {
    parse(str: string, options?: { folder: string; ext: string }): string;
};
Object.defineProperty(window, 'twemoji', {
    value: {
        parse: str => str,
    },
});
```

and `src/typings.d.ts`:

```js
declare var twemoji: {
    parse(str: string, options?: { folder: string; ext: string }): string;
};
```

But this does not seem to solve the problem, as I still get error TS2304. I seem to get some inconsistent behavior, as it seems to work sometimes? Looking forward to a solution/explanation :)

Comment: Have you tried `window['twemoji'] = { value: { parse: str => str } };`?

Comment: yes I have tried adding twemoji on the window

Comment: I tried it on my system and it works for me. Is your jest|GlobalMocks.ts file added to the "setupFilesAfterEnv" array in your jest config?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thoughts:

1. try to install [types for twemoji](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/twemoji?activeTab=readme)
2. basically `src/typings.d.ts` should work. Does it included to the compilation process? Is it listed in your tests tsconfig `files` or `include` section? You can check it running `tsc --project=tsconfig.spec.json --outDir=output --listFiles`
3. try to change code in `typings.d.ts` to this:

```
    declare module 'twemoji' {
      export function parse(str: string, options?: { folder: string; ext: string }): string;
    }
```

Comment: Tried point 3 with no success. But installing the types did it for me. Thanks @nickbullock.

Comment: So in an Angular CLI setup, where should the `typings.d.ts` file be inlcuded? Is it not included because the `tsconfig.app.json` has an `files` entry with `.`, and the `tsconfig.spec.json` extands the `tsconfig.app.json`?

Comment: @DauleDK in ng new project i can see that `tsconfig.spec.json` extends `tsconfig.json` and has option  "include": [
    "src/**/*.spec.ts",
    "src/**/*.d.ts"
  ], so your typings.d.ts will be included by `src/**/*.d.ts` rule